# How can I summarize a table in Power BI and give me a list of the summarized column

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, I create a summary table by using summarizecolumns() function on a Table called `Orders`,

```
Summary = summarizecolumns('Orders'[month], "month", sum('Order'[day]))
```

My Orders table looks like

| month | day | ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jan | 1 | 34 |
| jan | 15 | 32 |
| feb | 16 | 23 |
| feb | 13 | 32 |

I would like the summary table to look lik

| month | day | ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jan | 16 | 34, 32 |
| feb | 29 | 23, 32 |

How can add a new column `ids` for showing the list of id getting summarized?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CONCATENATEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax), eg

```
Summary = summarizecolumns('Orders'[month], 
                            "days", sum('Orders'[day]), 
                            "ids", CONCATENATEX(Orders, FORMAT(Orders[id],"General Number"),  ", " ))
```